# Running a Bitcoin node (behind Firewall / NAT or anything else? disallowing inbound connections)

Tags: full-node, network, firewall

I consider running a bitcoin full node on a raspberry Pi 3. I want to attach the raspberry Pi into my home-network (wifi). When I check my IP address I have a public address to the outside (which is changing from time to time, however is only one of 5 different addresses) and via NAT given by my ISP. I don't know what is between "my" public IP and my homenetwork in detail.

As I understand it correctly a bitcoin node does only good to the overall network iff it can accept inbound connections, therefore my raspberry pi must be publicly available (behind all this NAT whatever). If I run a bitcoin node I would like to use it at least by myself as a trusted node inside my mobile bitcoin wallet...

In the end I see two ways to do that:

- Resolve NAT issues with one of the following techniques: Upnp, TURN, NAT hole punching, STUN, ICE, IGDP, NAT-PMP, PCP, ALG, wathever else there, I don't know...
- Or running a hidden service.

So my question:

- Is it good/bad/ok to "only" allow inbound connections as a tor hidden service?
- Is there an easy way to get a bitcoin node with "traditional" means available as a public node inside a home network?

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to attempt the following: Your router most likely offers you a GUI so you can adjust a few settings. Use your browser to connect to your router whose ip address is something like `192.168.0.1`. This will bring the GUI to your browser (you will need to find out the login details giving you access). Once you are connected to your router, there is probably a section called 'advanced settings'. Within that section, you may see a subsection called 'DHCP reservation' which should allow you to choose a fixed internal ip address for your raspberry. Once you have done that, go back to advanced settings and find a subsection called 'port forwarding`. This will allow you to instruct your router to forward any connection attempt on port 8333 to your fixed ip address.

In fact, I have just been paraphrasing [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#enabling-connections)

Comment: This sounds very logical to me! And might work in some cases, however is this a general solution? Could an ISP have something in place, which won't allow such a thing! My guess is, that behind a single public IP address an ISP is hiding several customers. In that case one has to deal with double NAT (NAT-over-NAT)? I will try if this works in my specific case, still I think this is not a general solution.

Comment: I have added the the link to the masters themselves. All I got is from them