# How do nodes communicate through tcp over different networks

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core-development

It is said that the nodes communicate over tcp but how is that acheived across networks over different Nats

Answer (score 2):

> **different networks**

Ordinary plain IP routing.

> **different Nats**

The Bitcoin network protocol uses standard TCP sockets with a typical destination TCP-port number of 8333.

The use of [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1631) by many last-hop routers makes it harder to connect to Bitcoin nodes that use IPV**4** [private addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) behind a router. In theory the use of IPV**6** addresses should make this issue go away.

I believe the [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal)  for Bitcoin IPV4 TCP connections probably uses whatever features are provided by the underlying network libraries and/or are configured in the OS by the end-user.

So far as I know, there isn't a Bitcoin-specific solution for this. There are a lot of general solutions that may be appropriate to use.

See

- [What is the NAT traversal technique used by bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61546/13866) - which has answers mentioning specific support for UPNP *if configured*.
- [Can exist bitcoin network with all nodes behind NAT?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43355/13866)
- [How does bitcoin core establish a peer to peer network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96925/13866)
- [Running a Bitcoin node (behind Firewall / NAT or anything else? disallowing inbound connections)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/49136/13866)

Comment: Yes, there is nothing special about Bitcoin in this regard compared to e.g. a Minecraft server. It's just plain old TCP/IP. NAT traversal is another matter; if a node behind a NAT wants to be accessible on the public internet, the NAT needs to be configured to forward traffic sent to a particular port on the public address to the node.